# The `ldapmodify` command hangs

Tags: ldap, openldap, apacheds

The `ldapmodify` command hangs:

```
$ ldapmodify -D "uid=admin,ou=system" -w secret -p 10389 -h localhost
```

But the `ldapsearch` command works fine:

```
$ ldapsearch -D "uid=admin,ou=system" -w secret -p 10389 -h localhost -b "ou=system"
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <ou=system> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# services, configuration, system
dn: ou=services,ou=configuration,ou=system
ou: services
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit

# sysPrefRoot, system
dn: prefNodeName=sysPrefRoot,ou=system
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: extensibleObject
prefNodeName: sysPrefRoot

# consumers, system
dn: ou=consumers,ou=system
ou: consumers
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit

# groups, system
dn: ou=groups,ou=system
ou: groups
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit

# admin, system
dn: uid=admin,ou=system
keyAlgorithm: RSA
privateKeyFormat: PKCS#8
displayName: Directory Superuser
sn: administrator
cn: system administrator
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: tlsKeyInfo
userCertificate:: MIIBgTCCASsCBgFZwG57UzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBCMQswCQYDVQQGEwJV
 UzEMMAoGA1UEChMDQVNGMRIwEAYDVQQLEwlEaXJlY3RvcnkxETAPBgNVBAMTCEFwYWNoZURTMB4XD
 TE3MDEyMTA5NDk0M1oXDTE4MDEyMTA5NDk0M1owUDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxDDAKBgNVBAoTA0FTRj
 ESMBAGA1UECxMJRGlyZWN0b3J5MR8wHQYDVQQDExZzdGVwaGFuZS1UaGlua1BhZC1YMzAxMFwwDQY
 JKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAJ8Vkmb185ftKslZiq4O3xwMvcn7POSHqicja6S/1Fd13RCZbcSl
 fryzcFToYxN7kDhWv/Sr17A+BAvnf+0LT/0CAwEAATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAANBAEmF0ag90ymJ4
 sd/l4DGwGu/gipm5Vjl9JjvVzCS7UuvKZ4l9g/FRcuMg9AmjGPsGOP06LgSM/oGUenOleUk9Hc=
userPassword:: c2VjcmV0
publicKey:: MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAJ8Vkmb185ftKslZiq4O3xwMvcn7POSHqi
 cja6S/1Fd13RCZbcSlfryzcFToYxN7kDhWv/Sr17A+BAvnf+0LT/0CAwEAAQ==
publicKeyFormat: X.509
uid: admin
privateKey:: MIIBUwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAT0wggE5AgEAAkEAnxWSZvXzl+0qyVmKr
 g7fHAy9yfs85IeqJyNrpL/UV3XdEJltxKV+vLNwVOhjE3uQOFa/9KvXsD4EC+d/7QtP/QIDAQABAk
 BOmpwSH6jTAq7HemTZiCOZeno0WN1HlfjvCcNgTiCfbaY20l34ydGw+6FsSINPh/sYv62AJEYIjk/
 5KWNTZFBBAiEA5lQyCefJ1BZzLX/X2qdZVVF7p0rEpZ0bHyzt043HN2UCIQCw0JsmXRbH9Qct4g/b
 MadK6a4QXTxy0LXjFqbZojKouQIgGdaoJmRSR/CcyyXkWSsc4m1ZqdLBbLLLMBwiMfFdv+ECIBdpq
 AGudePIWEkFFCBsNMDArKHSFr0FUfBeAX3z8k1RAiB5RI7iYw1alVEaXtL2TMyLxp4UlIi/xCtBFd
 7N988icg==

# system
dn: ou=system
ou: system
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: extensibleObject

# partitions, configuration, system
dn: ou=partitions,ou=configuration,ou=system
ou: partitions
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit

# interceptors, configuration, system
dn: ou=interceptors,ou=configuration,ou=system
ou: interceptors
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit

# configuration, system
dn: ou=configuration,ou=system
ou: configuration
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit

# Administrators, groups, system
dn: cn=Administrators,ou=groups,ou=system
uniqueMember: 0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1=admin,2.5.4.11=system
cn: Administrators
objectClass: top
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames

# users, system
dn: ou=users,ou=system
ou: users
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 12
# numEntries: 11
```

I just built and installed the `apacheds-2.0.0-M23` and `openldap-2.4.44` products on my `Lubuntu 16.04` box.

Comment: What do you mean hang ? Does it mean that you write the command and press enter and then nothing shows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ldapmodify reads from stdin, because you didn't specify an LDIF file via -f.

Comment: That was it. I added a -f myfile.ldif and it did work.